# Explaining .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Can someone please explain to me what these `.htaccess` rules mean?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it step by step:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

> [From Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews):
>
> A **Multiviews** search is enabled by the **Multiviews Options**. If the server receives a request for `/some/dir/foo` and `/some/dir/foo` does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named `foo.*`, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that document.

---

```
RewriteEngine On
```

> [From Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine):
>
> The **RewriteEngine** directive enables or disables the runtime rewriting engine. If it is set to off this module does no runtime processing at all. It does not even update the `SCRIPT_URx` environment variables.
>
> Use this directive to disable rules in a particular context, rather than commenting out all the RewriteRule directives.
>
> Note that rewrite configurations are not inherited by virtual hosts. This means that you need to have a RewriteEngine on directive for each virtual host in which you wish to use rewrite rules.

---

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This rule will catch any request with a trailing slash, for example `http://www.example.com/test/`.

In this request only the `test` part will be catch because the trailing `/` is outside the capture brackets `( )`.

Then it will redirect the user to `http://www.example.com/` + the catch string `test`: `http://www.example.com/test`. The `[L]` flag means that no other rules will be checked. The `[R=301]` flag means that the user will be redirected with a `301` code to this page.

So the purpose of this rule is to remove trailing slashes.

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This part is typically called a Dispatcher. Any request that is not pointing to a file (`%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`) or a directory (`%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`) will be sent to `index.php`.

The purpose of this rule is to redirect rewritten queries like `http://www.example.com/user/1/florian` (there is no folder `user/1/` with a file named `florian` on the filesystem) to index.php who will be able to handle this request.

Comment: Thank you @Florian for your detailed explanation. it was very helpful. I have got one more question though. if a url is not valid then it is redirected to index.php(according to RewriteRule ^ index.php). However even in this case $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] is the original uri which i executed not /index.php. why is that ?

Comment: Because it's a logical rewriting not a redirection. From the doc: `'REQUEST_URI':
The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'`. To get the rewritten path: `'PATH_TRANSLATED':
Filesystem- (not document root-) based path to the current script, after the server has done any virtual-to-real mapping.` [Here is the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: @rishi won't you mind accepting this answer to mark your question as solved if it helped you? [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)